# css media queries not working for certain resolutions

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using css media breakpoints in order to optimize fonts and such for different devices. Everything works except for two of my breakpoints but in an odd way.

I'm using the Google Chrome developer console to test all of these. The `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1440px) and (max-device-width: 1919px)` is for a device that is `1440px x 900px` so the width is 1440.

However, the media query will only work if i set it to `@media screen only and (min-device-width: 900px) and (max-device-width: 1919px)` which doesn't make any sense to me.

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 500px) {
  /* Works */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 960px) and (max-device-width: 1023px) {
  /* Works */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1279px) {
  /* Works */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1360px) and (max-device-width: 1439px) {
  /* Works */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1440px) and (max-device-width: 1919px) {
  /* Doesn't Work */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) and (max-device-width: 2499px) {
  /* Works */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2500px) and (max-device-width: 3839px) {
  /* Works */
}
```

Comment: how are you measuring the device width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVKLOM

I changed around some values. there were gaps in widths.

```
.test {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #e41;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 400px;
}



  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .test::before { content: '320px - 959px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .test::before { content: '960px - 1023px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1359px) {
  .test::before { content: '1024px - 1359px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1360px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
  .test::before { content: '1360px - 1439px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
  .test::before { content: '1440px - 1919px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2499px) {
  .test::before { content: '1920px - 2499px'; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 2500px) and (max-width: 3839px) {
  .test::before { content: '2500px - 3839px'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but after many hours of confusion, it turns out I was missing: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.

Now everything is back to normal -.-